# Tab completion in bash for definition of bash functions?

Tags: bash, command-line

I have several functions in my `~/.bash_profile` named `pg_dump_[dbname]_[envname]` so I would like to enter

```
type pg_dump [tab]
```

(or some other command besides *type*) for bash to show the definitino of that function.  Is this a builtin for *osx* that I am missing how to use or is there a third party to do this?

Comment: As far as I can see this works out of the box for me. Which version of bash are you using?

Comment: @nohillside  I messed up the question: I had intended to ask about showing the definition of the function. The title of the question and the contents have been updated. My bad.

Comment: You can add some auto completion by using COMPREPLY, COMP_WORDS and COMP_CWORD example [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/26/adding-bash-completion-for-your-own-tools-an-example-for-pss).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ksh/bash/zsh, you want:

```
$ typeset -f name_of_the_function
```

That will display the definition.

Comment: My question is about how to get automatic listing of the function names.  Yes `typeset -f` can show the definition- but so does `type` itself: but it seems neither one can use tab completion to find the available functions meeting a prefix

Comment: Yes, `type` shows the function definition, but only in `bash`.  The shell should already be completing the defined functions when they are first on the command line.  If you are expecting them to be completed as an argument to some other command, `ksh` won't do that.  `Bash` or `zsh`, you'd have to write your own completion logic to change what the shell tries to complete against post first entry on the command line.

Comment: ok upvoted for the info since it applies to other shells (useful for other folks)